# How to read from front buffer using glReadPixels?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL ES in Android to render certain images. As soon as i render the frame, I want to take a copy of it. Although I can use FBO for that, only certain devices support FBO. For other devices, I will have to use glReadPixels which consumes more time. Since glReadPixels can copy only the data from back buffer, the buffer can be swapped only after taking a copy which affects the response time for rendering.

Is there any way to copy data from frontbuffer. So that i can render the images to screen as soon as processing is over and take the copy later from front buffer.

EDIT: In some devices the back buffer gets cleared as soon as the buffer is swapped with the front buffer. In some other devices, it is not cleared. I would prefer the image to stay as it is in the backbuffer even after swapping it to front buffer ( rather copying it to front buffer). Is there any way to force the gl not to clear the backbuffer even after swapping?

Comment: Why do you not want to copy from the backbuffer before swapping? The response time will slow by a few milliseconds max (compare that to the human reaction time of 300ms).

Comment: No. Actually the glReadPixels took about 300ms in devices like HTC wildfire.

Comment: Woah, okay you have a fair argument then..

Answer (score 1):

<s>Switch the reading to the front buffer using</s>

```
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
```

Comment: But glReadBuffer is not available in OpenGL ES. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641017/converting-glreadbuffer-gldrawbuffer-calls-into-opengl-es

Comment: Sorry, I always forget about this.